# How can I create a bar chart using R for Multiple Choice Answers

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I would like to visualize a bar chart for respondents residing in 3 districts in a city.

1. The district of stay are Gasabo, Kicukiro and Nyarugenge.
2. The questions they responded has multiple choices and they can choose more that one.

   ```
      library (dplyr)
      Barrier_ogd <- ogd_data_new %>%
        select(District_of_stay, Q19_Application_Barriers_to_Ogd_Usage) %>%
        group_by(District_of_stay, Q19_Application_Barriers_to_Ogd_Usage) %>% 
        summarise(count = n()) %>%
   ```
3. I want to collapse all answer choices into one bar graph for each multiple responses for each of the district
4. For a sample data set, I am interested in Column 6 and column 29.
   [Sample dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TLw-UG8WOlFQ3dCn4Kmdok6I2rJL3M31oYb4_a_AxjU/edit?usp=shar)
5. How would I proceed to visualize the final bar chart?
6. Is there a way we can present the bar charts as follows:[image: sample image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the data, it seems you need to split the responses that are currently separated by commas into multiple rows:

```r
library(tidyverse)

ogd_data_new %>%
  rename(Q19 = Q19_Application_Barriers_to_Ogd_Usage) %>%
  separate_rows(Q19, sep = ", ") %>%
  filter(nzchar(Q19)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Q19)) %>%
  count(District_of_stay, Q19) %>% 
  group_by(District_of_stay) %>%
  ggplot(aes(District_of_stay, n, fill = Q19)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Blues") +
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("Q19: Application Barriers to Ogd Usage")
```

[image]

---

**Edit**

An alternative representation:

```r
ogd_data_new %>%
  rename(Q19 = Q19_Application_Barriers_to_Ogd_Usage) %>%
  separate_rows(Q19, sep = ", ") %>%
  filter(nzchar(Q19)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(Q19)) %>%
  count(District_of_stay, Q19) %>% 
  group_by(District_of_stay) %>%
  ggplot(aes(Q19, n, fill = Q19)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = n), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            color = "white", fontface = 2, size = 5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#8C1A1A", "#D82828", "#E55B5B",
                               "#B3B2B3", "#3B3BE4", "#0000D7", "#02008B")) +
  facet_grid(.~District_of_stay) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(nrow = 4)) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "bottom") +
  ggtitle("Q19: Application Barriers to Ogd Usage")
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way we can present the bars for the choices in the legend to be individual, and give each a different colour rather than in a stack? @Allan Cameron

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you are after but here there in an example of how you could summarise for question 6:

```
read_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TLw-UG8WOlFQ3dCn4Kmdok6I2rJL3M31oYb4_a_AxjU/edit#gid=1430333482') %>%
  count(District_of_stay, Q6_Know_Opd_Available_Use_by_Anybody) %>%
  rename(district = District_of_stay, 
         question = Q6_Know_Opd_Available_Use_by_Anybody) %>%
  ggplot(aes(district, n, fill = factor(question))) +
  geom_col() +
  labs(title = 'Q6: Know Opd Available Use by Anybody',
       fill = 'Answers', x= '')
```

[image]